# How to create a line chart in c# using data from database?

Tags: c#, database, loops, charts, linechart

I want to create a line chart where in x axis I will have dates and in y axis I will have prices.

I have createad an list of all the dates and prices from the database.

```
var ListOfDates = DBaccess.GetOperationToList().Select(x =>x.Data.ToString());
var ListOfPrices = DBaccess.GetOperationToList().Select(x => x.Price);

for (int i = 0; i < ListOfDates.Count(); i++)
{
    chart2.Series["s1"].Points.AddXY(ListOfPrices, ListOfPrices);
}
```

When I want to create points I have the following mistake "Points od data doesn't work value type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'. You can use Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, Datetime, short, ushort."

But the Data in ListOfDates have Datetime type, and the Price have Double type. How do I change the type?

Comment: Maybe: `AddXY(ListOfDates[i], ListOfPrices)[i]);`? But onit the ToString from the DataTime so it will add the real type, not strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell the `Series` what the real data type is use this:

```
chart2.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

You could add the `DataPoints` in a loop as in your code, but you will have to use the elements, not the whole list:

```
chart2.Series["s1"].Points.AddXY(ListOfDates[i], ListOfPrices[i]);
```

This assumes the the two lists are aligned with equal lengths.

But it is recommended to use `DataBinding`.

If your data source has **named properties** you can use this form of databinding:

```
chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(datalist, "date", datalist, "price");
```

If it hasn't, you can create a **combined** DataSource like so:

```
var ListOfData = DBaccess.GetOperationToList()
                         .Select(x => new { date = x.Data, price = x.Price});
```

and then bind it:

```
 chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBind(ListOfData, "date", "price", "");
```

Note that if you add the x-values as strings, as you did, they will be stored as `0s` and you won't be able to use them for anything, neither formatting nor searching nor aligning points of series.